# Is there a way to specify the PR branch for YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a way to just specify that a pipeline runs on the PR branch? I am fairly new to Azure Devops Pipeline YAML.

Currently the trigger is:

```
trigger:
- master
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can be done via:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - features/*
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers